# mac ox replacing strings in terminal

Tags: bash, terminal, csh

I would like to replace a string in a bunch of text files with another string. Suppose I have `*.txt` files with values of `INDEF` and I would like to replace them with `0000`?

Is there a command in bash/csh that I can use to do this (sed/cat)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this:

```
sed -i -- 's/INDEF/0000/g' *.txt
```

It will replace it in all you txt files

Comment: Another way of doing btw is :

    find . -name '*txt' -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i "" "s/INDEF/0000/g"

Comment: It's like putting a nail in a wall with a screwdriver. It works, but this is not the easiest way :) @Matuba

Comment: @Matuba btw, if the answer solved you problem, don't hesitate to accept it ;)

Comment: Just accepted, thanks again for the quick response to my problem!